# SSH freezes after reboot

Tags: linux, ssh, raspberry-pi

I am using Raspberry Pi 3 with Raspbian Stretch Lite installed on it. Sometimes when I reboot my rpi, I cannot login through ssh afterwards. There are 4 possible scenarios after reboot:

1. `Connection refused` error all the time.
2. PuTTy hangs after entering password, just no error is produced.
3. I can log, but entering any command in PuTTy results in no response.
4. When connectin with PuTTy just black screen, even no password prompt.

My `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file has only these lines uncommented:

```
PermitRootLogin yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
UsePAM yes
X11Forwarding yes
PrintMotd no
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

EDIT: output of `ssh -v`

```
ssh -v root@10.24.1.52
OpenSSH_7.4p1 Raspbian-10+deb9u1, OpenSSL 1.0.2l  25 May 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 10.24.1.52 [10.24.1.52] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4p1 Raspbian-10+deb9u1
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few things you can do to debug the problem.

1. Use verbose mode on the client side (ssh -v / ssh -vv / ssh -vvv); you seem to have exercised that option already
2. Inspect logs on server side (Raspberry Pi), cat /var/log/auth
3. Inspect network connection between client (PC that runs PuTTy) and server (Raspberry Pi). Is it wired/wireless? Is there any extra network equipment in between, like router/firewall?